# Windows Phone 7 Azure Mobile services

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure

I wanted to use the new Mobile service available on Azure for my Windows Phone 7 project. But cannot figure out what to include in the project in order to make this work. The "new Windows Phone 8 app" option works fine, however I would like to get this service into a Windows Phone 7 app.

Answer (score 1):

Although the Mobile Services team has not released an official WP7 SDK, you can find an unofficial one here: https://github.com/zaxy78/azure-mobile-wp7-sdk.

You can also access the REST API directly, reference is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj710108.aspx

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

"Azure Mobile Services" is just a set of Azure services packaged for mobile platforms.  Right now Windows Phone 7 is not supported, considering it is a deprecated platform (for Windows Phone 8 and not backwards compatible) I would not expect it to be supported.

However, since "Azure Mobile Services" is just a "packaged set of services" you can absolutely use Azure services in a Windows Phone 7 app it is just not "packaged in one spot" for you.

You could use the Windows Phone Toolkit (open source) for Windows Phone 7 phones...
http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Windows-Phone-Push-Notifications-and-Windows-Azure

However, most things in Azure expose RESTful APIs..so you could call the REST APIs for the specific Azure service.  For example:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prathul/archive/2012/08/10/windows-phone-amp-azure-service-bus-rest-authentication-and-messaging.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The latest [pre-release version of the Windows Azure Mobile Services client (0.3.3-rc) on NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices/0.3.3-rc) now supports both Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 7.1 apps, along with Windows Store apps.